# Download file through code that has a redirect?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some urls in the database. The problem is there urls are urls that redirect to what I want.

I have something like this

http://www.mytestsite.com/test/test/?myphoto=true

now if I go to this site it would do a redirect to the photo so the url would end up being

http://www.mytestsite.com/test/myphoto.jpg

Is it possible to somehow scrape(download) through C# and then have it redirect and get the real url so I can download the image?

Comment: It doesn't help that all of those links are broken.  You know, you can use php to serve images.  If you did it through HTML redirects, you would have to parse the HTML and search for a redirect tag.  Doing it through javascript would be a collosal pain.

Comment: @Wug - who said anything about php or javascript?  He's not serving anything, he wants to download images that are accessed from the server via a redirect.  It would not appear that he controls the server.

Comment: Nope I do not control the server do. I need to move hundreds of imgs to new servers so I need to download them but some of the links I have are links that sole purpose is to go to a pg and redirect to the actual img(not clue why they did this and not just have direct link to the img). I can't give valid links(and I don't know any public sites that do this) as this is company property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are after the [HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) Property. The property gets or sets a value that indicates whether the request should follow redirection responses.

**Example taken from MSDN**

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");    
myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Exactly what I looking for!! Did not think of httpWebRequest was just looking at Webclient(what I usually use).

Comment: I think it should also be mentioned that you have to close myHttpWebResponse. It seems if you try to then use WebClient right after it give you lots of timeouts.

Comment: @chobo2 yes your right it MSDN should mention that as a necessary/good practise

Answer (score 3):

I had issues trying to get `HttpWebRequest` to always fully redirect when using it with SharePoint external URLs; I simply couldn't get it to work.

After a lot of faffing about I discovered that this **can** be done with `WebClient` too and that proved more reliable for me.

To get that to work with `WebClient` you seem to have to create a class that derives  from `WebClient` so that you can manually force `AllowAutoRedirect` to true.

I wrote up a bit more on this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883808/1879019), which borrows its code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394761/how-to-turn-on-autoredirect-for-webclient).

The key code was:

> ```
> class CustomWebclient: WebClient
> {
>   [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
>   public CustomWebclient(): base()
>  {
>  }
>  public CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
>
>
>  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri myAddress)
>  {
>        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(myAddress);
>        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
>       {
>            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer =   cookieContainer;
>            (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
>       }
>       return request;
>   }
> }
> ```