# Downloading a file from a redirection page

Tags: c#

How would I go about downloading a file from a redirection page (which itself does some calculations based on the user).

For example, if I wanted the user to download a game, I would use WebClient and do something like:

```
client.DownloadFile("http://game-side.com/downloadfetch/");
```

It's not as simple as doing

```
client.DownloadFile("http://game-side.com/download.exe");
```

But if the user were to click on the first one, it would redirect and download it.

Comment: show actual code.You need to explain yourself better and induce the tech used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file through code that has a redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749676/download-file-through-code-that-has-a-redirect)

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should go with slightly customized `WebClient` class like that. It will follow code 300 redirects:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        return response;
    }
}
...
WebClient client=new MyWebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://game-side.com/downloadfetch/", "download.zip");
```

Comment: This did not work for me, however a similar approach that did work can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883808/1879019

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible with DownloadFile();

You could use this

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://game-side.com/downloadfetch/");    
myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

See also

[Download file through code that has a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749676/download-file-through-code-that-has-a-redirect)

Comment: So this question is a duplicate? Why do you answer it then?